# Optimal elimination and scoring system for three-team tournament?

Tags: scoring

We are planning a casual "sports" event with my friends for the summer. These sports events include a series of beer pong and molkky (a Finnish throwing game) matches throughout two evenings. There will be three teams with two members in each team. One match for both sports lasts around 30min.

The system I have drafted is based on three-team double elimination (3TDE). For beer pong, we will have two rounds of 3TDE - one elimination round held during the first evening and one during the second evening. The winners of these eliminations advance to the final match. If the same team wins both eliminations, it will be declared as winner and no final will be held. Each won match will yield 1 point. For molkky, we will have only one 3TDE round and the winner of the elimination round will be declared winner. Each won match will yield 3 points to balance it out with the beer pong matches.

For some reason I'm getting a feeling this might not be a very optimal way of going about this. Is the points system "pointless" (no pun intended)? Should I have two rounds of 3TDE for molkky as well? One possibility would be to use a round-robin system, but there's the possibility that it will need a tiebreaker match if a "circle of death" is achieved (all teams win and lose once).

Can you think of any better alternatives or more optimal systems for this sort of setup?

Comment: [round-robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament)?

Comment: Round robin does not work for three teams even even if points are involved.   You just beat a team and then they are champs?